# Draggable item get hidden behind other UI elements - Qt Qml

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qml

In my application window I have two `ItemPanel`s which is orgnized inside a `RawLayout`.

```
Item {
    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 1

        ItemPanel {
            Layout.preferredWidth: 250
            Layout.fillHeight: true

            panelHeader: "Components"

            DraggableItem {
                width: 100; height: 100;
            }
        }


        ItemPanel {
            Layout.preferredWidth: 250
            Layout.fillHeight: true

            panelHeader: "Actions"
        } 
    }
}
```

The `Components` panel contains `DraggableItem`s. Droppable area is the `Actions` panel. But if I tried to drag an `DraggableItem` to the `Actions` panel, it will be hidden while I'm dragging it.

[image: gif of the issue]

## DraggableItem

```
Item {
    id: root
    property string colorKey: "red"

    width: 64; height: 64

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea

        width: 64; height: 64
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        drag.target: tile

        onReleased: parent = tile.Drag.target !== null ? tile.Drag.target : root

        Rectangle {
            id: tile

            width: 64; height: 64
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

            color: colorKey

            Drag.keys: [ colorKey ]
            Drag.active: mouseArea.drag.active
            Drag.hotSpot.x: 32
            Drag.hotSpot.y: 32
            states: State {
                when: mouseArea.drag.active
                ParentChange { target: tile; parent: root }
                AnchorChanges { target: tile; anchors.verticalCenter: undefined; anchors.horizontalCenter: undefined }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was thinking adding a transparent layer and change the parent to it while dragging but I have no idea how to add a new layer on top of everything. Any other workarounds for this?

Comment: Did you try to sex [z property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#z-prop) of `DraggableItem` greater then both `ItemPanel`s?

Comment: @folibis: It is the z-value of the `ItemPanel` "Components" that should be greater. The z-value of its children is less relevant, unless they are reparented to become siblings of the `ItemPanel`s.

Comment: Adding z value to ItemPanel does not work. I added z:1 for first ItemPanel and 200 to the Actions panel.

Comment: Of course, if the z for Actions-panel is greater, it will fail again. The higher the `z-value` of an object, the higher it is layered - relative to the siblings. If the z-value is the same, the one added the last will be layerd on top. A negative value will layer the object beneeth the parent. *z values are always only relative to the siblings.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to change the `z`-value of the `ItemPanel` with the `panelHeader: "Components"` to something greater than the siblings. Then automatically, all the children will be layered above them, too.

Reparenting is also a good solution. If you use `ApplicationWindow` as root object in your project, you don't even need to create add a new layer - it is already there.

You can use the *attached property* `ApplicationWindow` to reparent your draggable to `ApplicationWindow.overlay`. The only challange left is, that you need to specify the right position. You can use [`mapToItem()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapToItem-method) and `mapFromItem()` for this.

If you don't have `ApplicationWindow` as root, you can add a regualr `Item` as a child to your root and set the `z`-value to be the greates among its siblings. Then you assing it an `id`. If you don't shadow this `id` (having the same name for other identifiers, beeing resolved with higher priority) you can adress this `Item` from wherever. See more on this [**here**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-documents-scope.html).

Comment: `<applicationWindowId>.overlay` as parent works. I also could use just the word `overlay` as parent.  I did not get `mapToItem()` thing. why would i be needed that?